# Finding probable number of meaningful English words for given number of blank spaces

Tags: java, javascript, nlp

I am currently looking for a piece of Java/JavaScript code to identify probable words for given blank spaces.

Example : Question -----

Answer : The given question has five blank spaces, I want to identify how many 5 length words are there in English to fill these blanks.

Comment: Doesn't sound like anything to do with nlp. Seems like you need to google and download a list of English words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on a mac, there's a list of all english words at `usr/share/dict/words`. Theres 1 word per line, so you can read in that file, split it by newline characters (`\n`) & store them in some object.

If you're always going to be looking for words based on length, you may also want to read the length of each word while your parsing for new lines, and put it in an appropriate array. For example, have some dictionary object with arrays for words of length 1 character, 2 characters, 3 characters, etc.